Load gnuplot-iostream.h with vcpkg
There is already a good answer for how to use gnuplot-iostream.h in C++ to plot graphs. I am trying to find a solution using vcpkg where instead of saving the gnuplot-iostream.h file in my project folder I install it using vcpkg so it is available for a wide range of projects. It is not a package that is included with vcpkg so I guess there may be a different route for including it. I am a user who finds microsoft documentation like this one impossible to decipher.

Are you asking how to contribute a vcpkg package for that header, or are you asking about CMake's ExternalContent mechanism (see also: CPM) for pulling down code in Cmake? You can use both approaches within the same cmake file, it's fine.

Thanks for your comment @Botje . Unfortunately you are talking to someone who can perhaps understand what you might mean when you write "contribute a vcpkg for that header" but is completely lost when he reads "CMake's ExternalContent mechanism." I guess I am looking for an idiots guide for how to make this header file available for all projects without having to copy/paste it to every project folder.

See linked question for the necessary FetchContent_Declare invocation, after which you can add the source directory as an include.

As an even simpler thing, you could just use git submodules...

@Botje thanks is there a reference for git submodules?

The official documentation.
